# How to get list of all installed packages along with version in composer?

Tags: composer-php

I have been working on a project using Symfony 2.1 on my local machine.  I have uploaded it to my server but when I try and install the vendor bundles using Composer, I'm getting a lot of dependency errors.  Presumably this is something to do with the latest version of Symfony just being released and my `composer.json` file not specifying exact version numbers.

Is there any way I can quickly display the version numbers of everything on my local machine?

Here is my composer.json file (which worked fine until a few days ago):

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "*",
        "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.1.x-dev",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.x-dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "*",
        "liip/imagine-bundle": "*",
        "simplethings/form-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
        "antimattr/google-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
        "genemu/form-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "behat/behat":                  "2.4.*@stable",
        "behat/mink":                   "1.4.*@stable",
        "behat/symfony2-extension":     "*@stable",
        "behat/mink-extension":         "*@stable",
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver":  "*@stable",
        "behat/mink-browserkit-driver":  "*",
        "liip/functional-test-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web"
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin/"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 748, accepted):

You can run `composer show -i` (short for `--installed`).

In the latest version just use `composer show`.

The `-i` options has been deprecated.

You can also use the `global` instalation of composer: `composer global show`

Comment: write this anyone trying to get this using composer.phar and php

Comment: The '-i' option is now deprecated. `composer show` lists installed package by default.

Comment: And probably goes without saying that `composer show --help` prints all the available options.

Comment: `composer show vendorName/packageName -a`  will show you all available versions and requires

Comment: using composer-link? looking for how to display list of linked packages? => `composer linked` :)

Answer (score 75):

To list the globally installed composer packages:

```
composer global show -i
```

Comment: as of 2021 you can simple use `composer global show`

Comment: " -i, --installed List installed packages only (**enabled by default**, only present for BC)." (BC = backwards compatibility)

Answer (score 31):

List installed dependencies:

- Flat: `composer show -i`
- Tree: `composer show -i -t`

`-i` short for `--installed`.

`-t` short for `--tree`.

ref: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#show

Comment: Thank you. I also found the `-t` flag very useful

Comment: The tree option -t was indeed helpful

Answer (score 25):

If you only want to check version for only one, you can do

```
composer show -- twig/twig
```

Note that only installed packages are shown by default now, and installed option is now deprecated.

Answer (score 14):

The behaviour of this command as been modified so you don't have to pass the `-i` option:

```
[10:19:05] coil@coil:~/workspace/api$ composer show -i
You are using the deprecated option "installed". 
Only installed packages are shown by default now. 
The --all option can be used to show all packages.
```

Answer (score 6):

Ivan's answer above is good:

`composer global show -i`

Added info:  if you get a message somewhat like:

`Composer could not find a composer.json file in ~/.composer`

...you might have no packages installed yet.  If so, you can ignore the next part of the message containing:

`... please create a composer.json file ...`

...as once you install a package the message will go away.

Answer (score 3):

With composer-runtime-api 2.0+ there is a new `InstalledVersions` class with some static methods to see things programmatically.

For example:

```php
// To list all packages (`string[]`)
\Composer\InstalledVersions::getInstalledPackages();

// To list every details of every packages
\Composer\InstalledVersions::getAllRawData();
```

More information: https://getcomposer.org/doc/07-runtime.md#installed-versions

Comment: I'm getting `Class 'Composer\InstalledVersions' not found` I have added `"composer-runtime-api": "^2.0"` to my require in composer.json. I can only test on AWS Elastic beanstalk but it seems its not installing my packages.

Comment: I'm running laravel 5.8 so it might have something to do with that.

Comment: It should work, do you know which version of composer you have?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install Symfony2.2, you can see the complete change in your `composer.json` [on the Symfony blog](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-2-2-0#upgrading).

Just update your file according to that and run `composer update` after that. That will install all new dependencies and Symfony2.2 on your project.

---

If you don't want to update to Symfony2.2, but have dependency errors, you should post these, so we can help you further.

Comment: Turns out the problems I was having were down the incompatibilities between FOS User bundle 2x and sonata user bundle

Comment: @Dan, I think it was because the SonataUserBundle was not configured the correct way. That was fixed yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a way to get it via $event->getComposer()->getRepositoryManager()->getAllPackages()