# Composer: List Project Scripts and Plugins?

Tags: php, composer-php, composer-plugin

Does composer have any built in way to display a list of plugins in the current project?  Or is the only option for finding composer plugins some sort of text search through the `composer.json` files in `vendor` with something like

```
$ find vendor -name composer.json | xargs grep -i -r 'composer-plugin'
```

Answer (score 8):

Since a Composer plugin must require the `composer-plugin-api` package (see [Composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/plugins.md#plugin-package)) you can list the plugins with this command:

> composer depends composer-plugin-api

More details here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#depends-why-

Answer (score 3):

You can run `composer show -i` (short for `--installed`).

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15186162/1348344

Comment: Useful information, thank you, but it doesn't show which of those packages are composer plugins (or am I missing something?)

Comment: Not a problem :) Even wrong answers can teach me something I didn't know :)

Answer (score 2):

`composer -i` would list the whole dependency tree.

I usually use `composer -s` to see which requires are defined in the root `composer.json`