# Composer updating codeception - phpunit does not update

Tags: phpunit, composer-php, codeception

I run

```
rm -rf vendor && composer update codeception/codeception -v
```

I get error:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
  Problem 1
    - The requested package phpunit/phpunit (locked at 4.1.6, required as 4.8.x-dev) is satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[4.1.6] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package behat/gherkin (locked at v2.3.5, required as ~4.4.0) is satisfiable by behat/gherkin[v2.3.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 3
    - behat/behat v2.5.5 requires behat/gherkin ~2.3.0 -> satisfiable by behat/gherkin[2.3.x-dev, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.2, v2.3.3, v2.3.4, v2.3.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - behat/behat v2.5.5 requires behat/gherkin ~2.3.0 -> satisfiable by behat/gherkin[2.3.x-dev, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.2, v2.3.3, v2.3.4, v2.3.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - behat/behat v2.5.4 requires behat/gherkin ~2.3.0 -> satisfiable by behat/gherkin[2.3.x-dev, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.2, v2.3.3, v2.3.4, v2.3.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - behat/behat v2.5.3 requires behat/gherkin ~2.3.0 -> satisfiable by behat/gherkin[2.3.x-dev, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.2, v2.3.3, v2.3.4, v2.3.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - behat/behat v2.5.2 requires behat/gherkin ~2.3.0 -> satisfiable by behat/gherkin[2.3.x-dev, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.2, v2.3.3, v2.3.4, v2.3.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - behat/behat v2.5.1 requires behat/gherkin ~2.3.0 -> satisfiable by behat/gherkin[2.3.x-dev, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.2, v2.3.3, v2.3.4, v2.3.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - behat/behat v2.5.0 requires behat/gherkin ~2.2.9 -> satisfiable by behat/gherkin[v2.2.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for behat/behat 2.5.* -> satisfiable by behat/behat[v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5].
```

Currently in require-dev there are following settings:

```
"phpunit/phpunit": "4.8.x-dev",
        "phpunit/dbunit": "1.3.*",
        "codeception/codeception": "2.2.7",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "1.4.*",
        "flow/jsonpath": "0.2.*",
        "behat/behat": "2.5.*",
        "behat/gherkin": "~4.4.0",
```

and also one not related translations package created by our company.

I am trying to update codeception to the latest version.

I have experimented setting phpunit various versions but I am not able to get rid of errors.

What I am doing wrong?

**Update**

I updated composer.json to use same versions of packages as in

```
composer show
```

output, except for

```
"zendframework/zend-crypt": "2.3.*",
```

Ran

```
composer update
```

Still getting errors:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - mabuzagu/pdo-dblib-module dev-master requires doctrine/doctrine-orm-module ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-orm-module[1.0.0, 1.1.0].
    - mabuzagu/pdo-dblib-module dev-master requires doctrine/doctrine-orm-module ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-orm-module[1.0.0, 1.1.0].
    - doctrine/doctrine-orm-module 1.0.0 requires doctrine/orm >=2.5,<2.7 -> satisfiable by doctrine/orm[v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5].
    - doctrine/orm v2.5.5 requires doctrine/common >=2.5-dev,<2.7-dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.5.x-dev, 2.6.x-dev, v2.5.0, v2.5.0-beta1, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - doctrine/orm v2.5.4 requires doctrine/common >=2.5-dev,<2.7-dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.5.x-dev, 2.6.x-dev, v2.5.0, v2.5.0-beta1, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - doctrine/orm v2.5.3 requires doctrine/common >=2.5-dev,<2.7-dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.5.x-dev, 2.6.x-dev, v2.5.0, v2.5.0-beta1, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - doctrine/orm v2.5.2 requires doctrine/common >=2.5-dev,<2.6-dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.5.x-dev, v2.5.0, v2.5.0-beta1, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - doctrine/orm v2.5.1 requires doctrine/common >=2.5-dev,<2.6-dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.5.x-dev, v2.5.0, v2.5.0-beta1, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - doctrine/orm v2.5.0 requires doctrine/common >=2.5-dev,<2.6-dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.5.x-dev, v2.5.0, v2.5.0-beta1, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - doctrine/doctrine-orm-module 1.1.0 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for mabuzagu/pdo-dblib-module dev-master -> satisfiable by mabuzagu/pdo-dblib-module[dev-master].
```

Why is that? It likely should not be updating anything now until I set some new version.

Comment: Delete composer.lock file.

Comment: @Naktibalda Only if there is ~100% code coverage, otherwise it may be risky

Answer (score 2):

### Just run `composer update`

> What I am doing wrong?

The problem is that you are trying to update a single package instead of updating the whole list of packages, as is required by the newer version of `codeception`.

As you can see in the error message, all other dependencies are eager to be updated, but are `locked` as they already have versions specified in the `composer.lock` file.

Removing the .lock file may help, but is not the 'right way'. Just tell composer explicitly to update everything according to `composer.json`.

**P.S.** You might also consider using `composer clear-cache` in your mentioned command in the future for cases when you just absolutely positively want to get every dependency downloaded and installed from scratch.

Comment: But the problem is that my team does not want to update all the packages, because something might break in the application. I try to update minimally what I can. But there is nothing else I can do? I could try to update all the packages which are required by codeception, but I would like to avoid to update non related packages.

Comment: @Darius.V It all depends on your `composer.json` file. If you want to freeze versions of other packages - just specify exact package versions in `composer.json` instead of flexible ones with wildcards. Then `composer update` won't try to update them at all. Ever :-)

Comment: I guess I can copy versions from composer show output http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185459/how-to-get-list-of-all-installed-packages-along-with-version-in-composer

Comment: @Darius.V I would advise brushing up on [versions in composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md) for understanding what format is acceptable and how it basically works before making any changes to versions.
As for copy-pasting versions from `.lock` file - yep, it should work, look for `version` property of a package which comes right after `name`. You don't have any `dev-master` versions, so specifying versions by commit hash is not needed.

Comment: But the problem is that some packages are not in the list, and trying to show version of one, getting error: "Package zendframework/zend-crypt not found"

Answer (score 1):

there are two points:

1. Composer often unable to perform update with dependencies.
2. Codeception is not bound to your project. (if you have not done otherwise on purpose )
   which lets you do:

   composer remove codeception/codeception

   +

   composer require "codeception/codeception:2.2.7"

p.s. had the same issue recently upgrading from 2.0