# Installation failed while installing Laravel's Valet due to conflicts

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.4, laravel-valet, symfony4

I was having some problems with Laravel's Valet, so I attempted to uninstall and reinstall. Upon reinstallation, when I type the command `composer global require laravel/valet` I get this extremely lengthy error

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v3.4.1
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/valet v2.0.6
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/valet v2.0.5
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/valet v2.0.4
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/valet v2.0.3
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/valet v2.0.1
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v3.4.0
- Conclusion: remove symfony/console v4.0.1
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.0.1
- symfony/process v2.7.0 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.10 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.11 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.12 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.13 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.14 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.15 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.16 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.17 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.18 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.19 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.2 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.20 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.21 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.22 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.23 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.24 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.25 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.26 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.27 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.28 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.29 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.3 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.30 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.31 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.32 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.33 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.34 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.35 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.36 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.37 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.38 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.39 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.4 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.5 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.6 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.7 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.8 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.7.9 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.0 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.10 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.11 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.12 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.13 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.14 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.15 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.16 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.17 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.18 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.19 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.2 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.20 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.21 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.22 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.23 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.24 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.25 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.26 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.27 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.28 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.29 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.3 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.30 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.31 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.32 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.4 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.5 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.6 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.7 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.8 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v2.8.9 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.0.0 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.0.1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.0.2 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.0.3 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.0.4 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.0.5 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.0.6 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.0.7 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.0.8 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.0.9 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.1.0 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.1.1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.1.10 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.1.2 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.1.3 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.1.4 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.1.5 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.1.6 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.1.7 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.1.8 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.1.9 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.2.0 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.2.1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.2.10 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.2.11 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.2.12 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.2.13 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.2.14 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.2.2 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.2.3 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.2.4 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.2.5 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.2.6 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.2.7 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.2.8 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- symfony/process v3.2.9 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- Conclusion: remove symfony/process v4.0.1|install symfony/process v2.7.0|install symfony/process v2.7.1|install symfony/process v2.7.10|install symfony/process v2.7.11|install symfony/process v2.7.12|install symfony/process v2.7.13|install symfony/process v2.7.14|install symfony/process v2.7.15|install symfony/process v2.7.16|install symfony/process v2.7.17|install symfony/process v2.7.18|install symfony/process v2.7.19|install symfony/process v2.7.2|install symfony/process v2.7.20|install symfony/process v2.7.21|install symfony/process v2.7.22|install symfony/process v2.7.23|install symfony/process v2.7.24|install symfony/process v2.7.25|install symfony/process v2.7.26|install symfony/process v2.7.27|install symfony/process v2.7.28|install symfony/process v2.7.29|install symfony/process v2.7.3|install symfony/process v2.7.30|install symfony/process v2.7.31|install symfony/process v2.7.32|install symfony/process v2.7.33|install symfony/process v2.7.34|install symfony/process v2.7.35|install symfony/process v2.7.36|install symfony/process v2.7.37|install symfony/process v2.7.38|install symfony/process v2.7.39|install symfony/process v2.7.4|install symfony/process v2.7.5|install symfony/process v2.7.6|install symfony/process v2.7.7|install symfony/process v2.7.8|install symfony/process v2.7.9|install symfony/process v2.8.0|install symfony/process v2.8.1|install symfony/process v2.8.10|install symfony/process v2.8.11|install symfony/process v2.8.12|install symfony/process v2.8.13|install symfony/process v2.8.14|install symfony/process v2.8.15|install symfony/process v2.8.16|install symfony/process v2.8.17|install symfony/process v2.8.18|install symfony/process v2.8.19|install symfony/process v2.8.2|install symfony/process v2.8.20|install symfony/process v2.8.21|install symfony/process v2.8.22|install symfony/process v2.8.23|install symfony/process v2.8.24|install symfony/process v2.8.25|install symfony/process v2.8.26|install symfony/process v2.8.27|install symfony/process v2.8.28|install symfony/process v2.8.29|install symfony/process v2.8.3|install symfony/process v2.8.30|install symfony/process v2.8.31|install symfony/process v2.8.32|install symfony/process v2.8.4|install symfony/process v2.8.5|install symfony/process v2.8.6|install symfony/process v2.8.7|install symfony/process v2.8.8|install symfony/process v2.8.9|install symfony/process v3.0.0|install symfony/process v3.0.1|install symfony/process v3.0.2|install symfony/process v3.0.3|install symfony/process v3.0.4|install symfony/process v3.0.5|install symfony/process v3.0.6|install symfony/process v3.0.7|install symfony/process v3.0.8|install symfony/process v3.0.9|install symfony/process v3.1.0|install symfony/process v3.1.1|install symfony/process v3.1.10|install symfony/process v3.1.2|install symfony/process v3.1.3|install symfony/process v3.1.4|install symfony/process v3.1.5|install symfony/process v3.1.6|install symfony/process v3.1.7|install symfony/process v3.1.8|install symfony/process v3.1.9|install symfony/process v3.2.0|install symfony/process v3.2.1|install symfony/process v3.2.10|install symfony/process v3.2.11|install symfony/process v3.2.12|install symfony/process v3.2.13|install symfony/process v3.2.14|install symfony/process v3.2.2|install symfony/process v3.2.3|install symfony/process v3.2.4|install symfony/process v3.2.5|install symfony/process v3.2.6|install symfony/process v3.2.7|install symfony/process v3.2.8|install symfony/process v3.2.9
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v3.3.14|keep symfony/process v4.0.1
- Installation request for symfony/console (locked at v4.0.1, required as ^4.0) -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v4.0.1].
- Installation request for laravel/valet ^2.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/valet[v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.3, v2.0.4, v2.0.5, v2.0.6].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.0.1|install symfony/process v2.7.0|install symfony/process v2.7.1|install symfony/process v2.7.10|install symfony/process v2.7.11|install symfony/process v2.7.12|install symfony/process v2.7.13|install symfony/process v2.7.14|install symfony/process v2.7.15|install symfony/process v2.7.16|install symfony/process v2.7.17|install symfony/process v2.7.18|install symfony/process v2.7.19|install symfony/process v2.7.2|install symfony/process v2.7.20|install symfony/process v2.7.21|install symfony/process v2.7.22|install symfony/process v2.7.23|install symfony/process v2.7.24|install symfony/process v2.7.25|install symfony/process v2.7.26|install symfony/process v2.7.27|install symfony/process v2.7.28|install symfony/process v2.7.29|install symfony/process v2.7.3|install symfony/process v2.7.30|install symfony/process v2.7.31|install symfony/process v2.7.32|install symfony/process v2.7.33|install symfony/process v2.7.34|install symfony/process v2.7.35|install symfony/process v2.7.36|install symfony/process v2.7.37|install symfony/process v2.7.38|install symfony/process v2.7.39|install symfony/process v2.7.4|install symfony/process v2.7.5|install symfony/process v2.7.6|install symfony/process v2.7.7|install symfony/process v2.7.8|install symfony/process v2.7.9|install symfony/process v2.8.0|install symfony/process v2.8.1|install symfony/process v2.8.10|install symfony/process v2.8.11|install symfony/process v2.8.12|install symfony/process v2.8.13|install symfony/process v2.8.14|install symfony/process v2.8.15|install symfony/process v2.8.16|install symfony/process v2.8.17|install symfony/process v2.8.18|install symfony/process v2.8.19|install symfony/process v2.8.2|install symfony/process v2.8.20|install symfony/process v2.8.21|install symfony/process v2.8.22|install symfony/process v2.8.23|install symfony/process v2.8.24|install symfony/process v2.8.25|install symfony/process v2.8.26|install symfony/process v2.8.27|install symfony/process v2.8.28|install symfony/process v2.8.29|install symfony/process v2.8.3|install symfony/process v2.8.30|install symfony/process v2.8.31|install symfony/process v2.8.32|install symfony/process v2.8.4|install symfony/process v2.8.5|install symfony/process v2.8.6|install symfony/process v2.8.7|install symfony/process v2.8.8|install symfony/process v2.8.9|install symfony/process v3.0.0|install symfony/process v3.0.1|install symfony/process v3.0.2|install symfony/process v3.0.3|install symfony/process v3.0.4|install symfony/process v3.0.5|install symfony/process v3.0.6|install symfony/process v3.0.7|install symfony/process v3.0.8|install symfony/process v3.0.9|install symfony/process v3.1.0|install symfony/process v3.1.1|install symfony/process v3.1.10|install symfony/process v3.1.2|install symfony/process v3.1.3|install symfony/process v3.1.4|install symfony/process v3.1.5|install symfony/process v3.1.6|install symfony/process v3.1.7|install symfony/process v3.1.8|install symfony/process v3.1.9|install symfony/process v3.2.0|install symfony/process v3.2.1|install symfony/process v3.2.10|install symfony/process v3.2.11|install symfony/process v3.2.12|install symfony/process v3.2.13|install symfony/process v3.2.14|install symfony/process v3.2.2|install symfony/process v3.2.3|install symfony/process v3.2.4|install symfony/process v3.2.5|install symfony/process v3.2.6|install symfony/process v3.2.7|install symfony/process v3.2.8|install symfony/process v3.2.9|install symfony/process v3.3.14
- laravel/valet v2.0.0 requires symfony/process ~2.7|~3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.28, v2.7.29, v2.7.3, v2.7.30, v2.7.31, v2.7.32, v2.7.33, v2.7.34, v2.7.35, v2.7.36, v2.7.37, v2.7.38, v2.7.39, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.3, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9, v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9, v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.10, v3.1.2, v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6, v3.1.7, v3.1.8, v3.1.9, v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.10, v3.2.11, v3.2.12, v3.2.13, v3.2.14, v3.2.2, v3.2.3, v3.2.4, v3.2.5, v3.2.6, v3.2.7, v3.2.8, v3.2.9, v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.3.10, v3.3.11, v3.3.12, v3.3.13, v3.3.14, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9, v3.4.0, v3.4.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.0, v4.0.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.1, v4.0.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.10, v4.0.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.11, v4.0.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.12, v4.0.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.13, v4.0.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.2, v4.0.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.3, v4.0.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.4, v4.0.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.5, v4.0.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.6, v4.0.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.7, v4.0.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.8, v4.0.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.9, v4.0.1].
- Installation request for symfony/process (locked at v4.0.1) -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.0.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

What exactly is going on here and why can't I globally install Valet? I realize it is probably some sort of dependency issue/conflict, but it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Can you type this in your terminal and report it back by edit your question: `composer global show -i -t`, so we know what's screwed up in the dependency map.

Comment: Do you have laravel/installer on your machine? If so, try removing that first `composer global remove laravel/installer` and then attempt the valet install again

Comment: What have you tried to resolve this problem? Which of the lines in that output are unclear to you?

Answer (score 1):

> Installation request for symfony/console (locked at v4.0.1, required as ^4.0)
>
> Installation request for symfony/process (locked at v4.0.1)

Your `symfony/console` and `symfony/process` packages are locked at v4.0.1  (as per your `composer.lock` file), and you're trying to install the `laravel/valet` package which requires `symfony/process` `~2.7|~3.0` as per:

```
$ composer show -a laravel/valet 2.0.6 | grep ^symfony
symfony/process ~2.7|~3.0
```

However you can only install one branch as per the following message:

> Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.x, v4.0.x].

So to see, which existing packages locked it (e.g. `symfony/process`), run:

```
composer global why symfony/process -t
```

Or upgrade to the latest `laravel/valet` (v2.0.8) which now supports `symfony/process` `~4.0`:

```
$ composer show -a laravel/valet | grep ^symfony
symfony/process ~2.7|~3.0|~4.0
```

See also: [How to resolve a "Can only install one of:" conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36611550/55075)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/27754096 to see a list of installed packages - is `symfony/console` listed with version 4.0.1 there? The Lavarel installer explicitly asks for v2.3 or v3.x of `symfony/console` so you probably have to remove `symfony/console` manually first through `composer global remove symfony/console` - or at least have a look at `composer global why symfony/console` to see why `symfony/console` was installed in that version

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this same issue, I know I'm two years too late but just in case someone still is having this issue, go to your Composer folder

/users/[name]/AppData/Roaming/Composer

Move EVERYTHING from that folder to a temporary folder, for backup. Just make sure that you MOVE (cut and paste), don't copy. That folder needs to be emptied.

Then

```
composer global require laravel/valet
```

And Bob's your Uncle.

Comment: ...sounds like this removes all other globally required packages, this does not look like a good idea

Comment: Since you would have backed up your original folder, you can easily bring back your json file and update your packages. It worked for me and fixed my problem. I was able to continue my work for my clients as if nothing had happened; but, as long as it does not "look" like a good idea to you, by all means, make sure no one trusts my fix. lol

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove your old composer: install

```
composer global remove laravel/installer
```

then install:

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```