# What version of the packages listed in my composer.json file are installed?

Tags: yii2, widget, composer-php, version

How can I tell what version of a widget is installed in my project? I'm using the yii2 framework and composer to handle package dependencies.

Is there a way I can check what version of the packages listed in my `composer.json` file are installed?

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get list of all installed packages along with version in composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185459/how-to-get-list-of-all-installed-packages-along-with-version-in-composer)

Comment: Check inside `composer.lock` - there are details for each installed package including it's version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can check what version of the packages listed in my composer.json file are installed?

Yes, simply use the [show](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#show) option: `php composer.phar show`

All available options are listet in the [docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md).