# Identifying versions of committed composer packages?

Tags: git, composer-php

I've got the option to take on a number of projects from a client. The projects use composer installed dependencies which are committed to the git repositories. Unfortunately, none of the projects has a composer file. I guess the previous developers forgot/didn't want to commit them.

I'm looking for a quick way to identify the composer packages with versions to reconstruct the composer file and ease the future maintenance of the projects. Does anyone know of a efficient way to identify the versions?

Comment: Might this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185459/how-to-get-list-of-all-installed-packages-along-with-version-in-composer?

Comment: Hey @evolutionxbox, thanks for pointing me to this. It didn't work because there isn't a composer.json/composer.lock file.

Comment: Is there a directory akin to node_modules? Maybe you could build a dependancy tree from that?

Comment: There is a vendor directory which contains some of the dependencies. I could reconstruct it manually by going through this and checking each folder in there for a composer.json file. Then add them manually and guessing the major version at least... That's the manual work I'd like to avoid @evolutionxbox

Comment: Indeed. In node I would use shrinkwrap to accomplish this task, but I don't think composer has such a package.

Comment: Have you got a link for this @evolutionxbox? I would like to see what the functionality is to learn a bit more.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap - I would run this and then rename `npm-shrinkwrap.json` to `package-lock.json`, but I would still have to do manual work to figure out the true dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @evolutionxbox

Answer (score 0):

As I've found out so far there is no easy way. The best would be reconstructing the composer.json from the

```
vendor/composer/installed.json
```

file. This contains all dependencies - direct and indirect - with exact versions. From there it takes some manual work to relax the versions a bit and test it continuously.

Src: https://twitter.com/thomaspetracco/status/996659342052032512