# Valet is working but can't create a new Laravel install?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-valet

I have valet working in the sense that I can ping .test domains and I even have a dummy index.php hello world in a "test" folder in the "builds" folder.

(I'd like to keep my sites in the "builds" folder)

I thought it was as simple as cd into the "builds" directory and then the command I thought was as simple as `laravel new blog` with 'blog' the name of the directory that would be created to house the new laravel install.

This is the error I get:

```
laravel new blog
-bash: laravel: command not found
```

If I run a `composer` command it shows that it IS accessible, i.e. I get the Composer logo etc.

What is it that is being done wrong?

Any idea how to problem solve this?

++++

```
composer global show
```

And here's the outcome:

```
Changed current directory to /Users/henry/.composer
doctrine/inflector            v1.3.0  Common String Manipulations with rega...
illuminate/container          v6.0.2  The Illuminate Container package.
illuminate/contracts          v6.0.2  The Illuminate Contracts package.
illuminate/support            v6.0.2  The Illuminate Support package.
laravel/valet                 v2.4.2  A more enjoyable local development ex...
mnapoli/silly                 1.7.1   Silly CLI micro-framework based on Sy...
nategood/httpful              0.2.20  A Readable, Chainable, REST friendly,...
nesbot/carbon                 2.24.0  A API extension for DateTime that sup...
php-di/invoker                2.0.0   Generic and extensible callable invoker
psr/container                 1.0.0   Common Container Interface (PHP FIG P...
psr/simple-cache              1.0.1   Common interfaces for simple caching
symfony/console               v4.3.4  Symfony Console Component
symfony/polyfill-mbstring     v1.12.0 Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring ext...
symfony/polyfill-php72        v1.12.0 Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP...
symfony/polyfill-php73        v1.12.0 Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP...
symfony/process               v4.3.4  Symfony Process Component
symfony/service-contracts     v1.1.6  Generic abstractions related to writi...
symfony/translation           v4.3.4  Symfony Translation Component
symfony/translation-contracts v1.1.6  Generic abstractions related to trans...
symfony/var-dumper            v4.3.4  Symfony mechanism for exploring and d...
tightenco/collect             v6.0.2  Collect - Illuminate Collections as a...
```

So, it appears I don't have it?

******** Does my bash profile have to be in the same directory? I think that might be the error...

Comment: Have you installed the `laravel/installer` package?

Comment: is there a way I can test? laravel -v doesn't work

Comment: `composer global show` this link can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185459/how-to-get-list-of-all-installed-packages-along-with-version-in-composer

Comment: Thanks - I pasted the results in my above question. So, it appears that Laravel is not installed? How can I make that global or do I add that to my "park" directory in Valet? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, download the Laravel installer using Composer:

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

Make sure to place Composer's system-wide vendor bin directory in your $PATH so the laravel executable can be located by your system. This directory exists in different locations based on your operating system; however, some common locations include:

macOS and GNU / Linux Distributions: `$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin`

Then you'll be able to execute `laravel new blog`

Comment: Thanks that seemed to work but now I get this error: Crafting application...
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/builds/laravel_xxx.zip): failed to open stream: Permission denied in.."

Comment: I need to make the diretory writeable?

Comment: Yes, or use sudo before.

Comment: Yes that seems to be working...you think maybe I installed valet in a system directory or something? (Thanks for your help btw)

Comment: I'm not sure, will have to see the complete configs. I guess that might be the issue.

Comment: @nitesh Kumar > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57967577/permission-based-issue-with-valet-so-it-seems that's the follow up - would REALLY appreciate any thoughts you might have there...