# Permission based issue with Valet (so it seems)

Tags: laravel, laravel-valet

I got Valet to work and .test domains can be pinged etc.

However, when I create a `laravel new test-site` I get a bunch of permission-based errors. I 'sudo'd' the laravel build but I was repeatedly warned not to do this.

If I then view the site on the browser this is the error I get:

[image]

and this:

[image]

So - is the problem that I placed my "sites" folder (which I can "builds") in an inappropriate section of my machine?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give permission to your storage directory.

In my local mac I generally do

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage/
```

But this is vunerable on server/production. I would suggest you should change directory ownership. so set your current user that you are logged in with as owner and the webserver user (www-data, apache, ...) as the group. You can try this:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data storage
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data bootstrap/cache
```

then to set directory permission try this:

```
chmod -R 775 storage
chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache
```

Webserver user and group depend on your webserver and your OS. to figure out what's your web server user and group use the following commands.

for nginx use:

```
ps aux|grep nginx|grep -v grep
```

for apache use:

```
ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'
```

Comment: Thanks. But if the files are pushed via git or other then the permissions are also sent with the files? Or is that not the case...

Comment: Permissions are also sent, but it doesn't matter when you pull on server, you will have to give the same permission again over there.

Comment: ok thanks for all of this - all very helpful. This is the first time I have experienced this and I have used MAMP, Homestead etc. Is this just because I installed my "sites" direcotory folder (i.e the main directory that contains the Laravel project files) in the wrong place?

Comment: No, this usually comes on Mac, I face this every time I do a fresh installation or clone new project from repository.

Comment: I definintely well - just a quick question - sorry it is a bit basic but with the command > sudo chmod -R 777 storage/ is "storage" and an example of a directory created by the user or is that a mac thing? (I am on a mac) thanks

Comment: Generally mac is secure and it doesn't give permission to servers, in case of laravel servers need to have permission to write the storage folder, it can be anything, say your blade templates are cached over there, whatever you upload through laravel application on browser etc. So in some cases you need to give an extra permission for the same. PS Storage is a folder created inside your laravel application when you created the application.

Comment: Thanks for your help you've been really helpful. So just to be clear, the "storage" folder is a preset Laravel directory that comes shipped with Laravel?

Comment: @henry yes it is.